# Convert JavaScript Time to PHP with Laravel Carbon

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am developing a website with Angular 8 as front end and Laravel(version:5.8.*) as back end. I want to store date selected by user in MySQL database. Posting the selected date by user as `2019-11-19T02:30:14.000Z`.
In `app.php` timezone has been declared as 'Asia/Kolkata'. I want to convert the js date to PHP date with specified timezone.
In my controller :

```
$date_no_timezone=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($request->from_time);
$date_with_timezone=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_no_timezone,'Asia/Kolkata');
```

But it doesn't return anything, showing 500 error.
NB: Iam a beginner in Laravel.

How can I do this task?

Comment: what does error show ?

Comment: @fahim152 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Check your servers error log or turn on display errors to see the real error message.

Comment: in your .env put APP_DEBUG=true , then run php artisan serve again. after that try again , now show us that error

Comment: you have a syntax error in that code. you forgot ')' at end of line one

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh Thankyou. Now the error has gone. But I got the output as `2019-11-19T06:13:34.000000Z`  for the input `2019-11-19T06:13:34.432Z`. Timezone didn't affected

Answer (score 1):

Finally a small change has done the trick. I changed my code to

`$date_no_timezone=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($request->from_time));
 $date_with_timezone=\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date_no_timezone,'Asia/Kolkata')->format('H:i:s');`

and it worked.

Comment: I think that's nonsense. Only the carbon object has a time zone. With your format method, you get a string without time zone information.
This works only if your local settings from the server also fit for 'Asia / Kolkata'. date() already returns your local time. Check that with var_dump ($date_no_timezone).

Comment: @jspit I have mentioned the local settings in the question. I think the question is clear and answer is straight forward